# User interactions on page interacting with HttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently attempting to find a way for a page to send information on user choices on a page to an HttpModule. For example, if a user either clicked a checkbox or not, the module could log that information for later error checking. My module can log simple data about the page, such as execution time, but I am hoping for more information.

Is such a thing possible? I have tried using Context.Items but have not found any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using bad event in IHttpModule that runs before you set Context.Items item. Try do it in event EndRequest where page was already processed.

In Page:

```
protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Context.Items["button_clicked"] = "yes";
}
```

in HttpModule:

```
public class DefaultHttpApplicationModule
    : System.Web.IHttpModule
{
   public virtual void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.EndRequest += context_EndRequest;
    }


    void context_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = ((HttpApplication)sender);
        var ctx = app.Context;
        string clicked = ctx.Items["button_clicked"] as string;
    }
}
```

You can also access the Page instance directly, becasu System.Web.UI.Page is also IHttpHandler.
There are two events HttpApplication.PreRequestHandlerExecute (Before Page events fired) and HttpApplicatoin.PostRequestHandlerExecute (It runs after Page.Unload).

```
    void context_PostRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = ((HttpApplication)sender);
        var ctx = app.Context;

        if (app.Context.Handler != null && app.Context.Handler is Page)
        { // Register PreRender handler only on aspx pages.
            Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        }
    }
```